# node js included route file does not allow end point

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node project and something very strange is happening. I have a routes file that has all of my routes and I import that on my server.js file. When I import the routes file. A get request of that route does not work at all, but when I paste that same route on the server.js it works as expected. Other routes in the file work correctly, but this one in particular does not work as expected. Code below. Thanks for any help.

server.js

```
require('./server/routes/mainRoutes.js')(app);
```

mainRoutes (this will not work):

```
app.get('/accounts',function(req,res){
        res.json({Test:'name'});
    });
```

Now if I put that /accounts route on the main server.js it will work. For some reason it never works in the imported mainRoutes file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's not working, It can help if you share the app initiation (I understand you use express?) and your use of `app.listen`.

Anyway, a best practice would be to use `app.use`, as follows:

server.js:

```
var routes = require('./server/routes/mainRoutes.js');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/', routes.app);
var server = app.listen(somePort, someIP, function() {
    console.log('Listening...');
});
```

mainRoutes.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/accounts',function(req,res){
    res.json({Test:'name'});
});
module.exports = {
    app: app
};
```